# Change file.name of file captured in <input type="file" />

Tags: javascript, html

How do I change the file.name that was captured in input tag:

```
<input type="file" />
```

Cause I want to replace if for example the file name has spaces I want to replace it with underscore. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can change only in Server side coding like `PHP`. After uploading using the `input` tag the file will be written in the server using server side code. you can change the filename there as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
$('input[type=file]').change(function(e){
    var in=$(this);
    var value1 = in.val().replace(/ /g,"_");
    $('input:radio[name="some_name"]').attr('value', 'value1');
});
```

Hope this helps..